# Why does the X or O not pop up when clicked?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I want to make a basic tic tac toe game that can be displayed on a website using Flask. I've got the grid out, but when a block is clicked, the X or O doesn't popup as expected.

This is my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="container">
           <button class="button-option"></button>
           <button class="button-option"></button>
           <button class="button-option"></button>
           <button class="button-option"></button>
           <button class="button-option"></button>
           <button class="button-option"></button>
           <button class="button-option"></button>
           <button class="button-option"></button>
           <button class="button-option"></button>
       </div>
       <button id="restart">Restart</button>
   </div>

   <div class="popup hide">
       <p id="message">Sample Message</p>
       <button id="new-game">New Game</button>
   </div>
   
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my JS code:

```js
let btnRef = document.querySelectorAll(".button-option");
let popupRef = document.querySelector(".popup");
let newgameBtn = document.getElementById("new-game");
let restartBtn = document.getElementById("restart");
let msgRef = document.getElementById("message");
//Winning Pattern Array
let winningPattern = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6],
];
//Player 'X' plays first
let xTurn = true;
let count = 0;

//Disable All Buttons
const disableButtons = () => {
  btnRef.forEach((element) => (element.disabled = true));
  //enable popup
  popupRef.classList.remove("hide");
};

//Enable all buttons (For New Game and Restart)
const enableButtons = () => {
  btnRef.forEach((element) => {
    element.innerText = "";
    element.disabled = false;
  });
  //disable popup
  popupRef.classList.add("hide");
};

//This function is executed when a player wins
const winFunction = (letter) => {
  disableButtons();
  if (letter == "X") {
    msgRef.innerHTML = "&#x1F389; <br> 'X' Wins";
  } else {
    msgRef.innerHTML = "&#x1F389; <br> 'O' Wins";
  }
};

//Function for draw
const drawFunction = () => {
  disableButtons();
  msgRef.innerHTML = "&#x1F60E; <br> It's a Draw";
};

//New Game
newgameBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  count = 0;
  enableButtons();
});
restartBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  count = 0;
  enableButtons();
});

//Win Logic
const winChecker = () => {
  //Loop through all win patterns
  for (let i of winningPattern) {
    let [element1, element2, element3] = [
      btnRef[i[0]].innerText,
      btnRef[i[1]].innerText,
      btnRef[i[2]].innerText,
    ];
    //Check if elements are filled
    //If 3 empty elements are same and would give win as would
    if (element1 != "" && (element2 != "") & (element3 != "")) {
      if (element1 == element2 && element2 == element3) {
        //If all 3 buttons have same values then pass the value to winFunction
        winFunction(element1);
      }
    }
  }
};

//Display X/O on click
btnRef.forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (xTurn) {
      xTurn = false;
      //Display X
      element.innerText = "X";
      element.disabled = true;
    } else {
      xTurn = true;
      //Display Y
      element.innerText = "O";
      element.disabled = true;
    }
    //Increment count on each click
    count += 1;
    if (count == 9) {
      drawFunction();
    }
    //Check for win on every click
    winChecker();
  });
});
//Enable Buttons and disable popup on page load
window.onload = enableButtons;
```

This is my python code:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

I think it's because I haven't rerendered the page, but to be honest I'm not very sure.

Answer (score 0):

this should do it!

```
let btnRef = document.querySelectorAll(".button-option");
let popupRef = document.querySelector(".popup");
let newgameBtn = document.getElementById("new-game");
let restartBtn = document.getElementById("restart");
let msgRef = document.getElementById("message");

// Winning Pattern Array
let winningPattern = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6],
];

// Player 'X' plays first
let xTurn = true;
let count = 0;
let gameOver = false;

// Function to check for a win
function checkWin(player) {
  for (let pattern of winningPattern) {
    if (
      btnRef[pattern[0]].innerText === player &&
      btnRef[pattern[1]].innerText === player &&
      btnRef[pattern[2]].innerText === player
    ) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

// Function to handle button clicks
function handleButtonClick(event) {
  const button = event.target;
  if (button.innerText === "" && !gameOver) {
    button.innerText = xTurn ? "X" : "O";
    xTurn = !xTurn;
    count++;

    if (checkWin("X")) {
      msgRef.innerText = "Player X wins!";
      disableButtons();
      gameOver = true;
    } else if (checkWin("O")) {
      msgRef.innerText = "Player O wins!";
      disableButtons();
      gameOver = true;
    } else if (count === 9) {
      msgRef.innerText = "It's a draw!";
      gameOver = true;
      disableButtons();
    }
  }
}

// Add click event listeners to buttons
btnRef.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", handleButtonClick);
});

// Disable All Buttons
function disableButtons() {
  btnRef.forEach((element) => (element.disabled = true));
  // Enable popup
  popupRef.classList.remove("hide");
}

// Enable all buttons (For New Game and Restart)
function enableButtons() {
  btnRef.forEach((element) => {
    element.innerText = "";
    element.disabled = false;
  });
  // Disable popup
  popupRef.classList.add("hide");
}

// New Game button click event
newgameBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  enableButtons();
  xTurn = true;
  count = 0;
  gameOver = false;
  msgRef.innerText = "";
});

// Restart button click event
restartBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  enableButtons();
  xTurn = true;
  count = 0;
  gameOver = false;
  msgRef.innerText = "";
});

// Initially enable buttons
enableButtons();
```